# Why is my project failing to reference the System.ComponentModel assembly?

Tags: mvvm-light, common-service-locator

My project is set to .NET Framework 4.5. I get the following error when attemping to use SimpleIOC (from MVVM Light) in my WPF project:

`Error    3   Reference required to assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the implemented interface 'System.IServiceProvider'. Add one to your project.`

I can't figure out why it's giving me this error. From what I understand, this is a mscorlib class so I'm not sure where it is getting System.ComponentModel from.

I can write `Dim test As IServiceProvider` without the compiler complainging. Is there some kind of version issue?

Comment: *From what I understand, this is a mscorlib class so I'm not sure where it is getting System.ComponentModel from.* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx `Assemblies:   mscorlib (in mscorlib.dll)
  System.ComponentModel (in System.ComponentModel.dll)`

Comment: I don't quite understand. Does that mean it's in both dlls? Or both dlls are required to use it? I can't find the System.ComponentModel.dll so I am unable to add it as a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a possible Visual Studio bug. I created a new WPF project and was able to find the System.ComponentModel.dll in the list of .Net Framework assemblies. For my current project, I ended up browsing to it to add a reference to it. All is well now.